# how to correct coding erorr?

Tags: java, sql, mysql, jdbc

java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).

```
if(agreementCbx.isSelected() == false){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
                    "Klik Centang CheckBox Untuk Simpan Data", "Error",
            JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }else {
            String typeHouse;
            if (t36RadioButton.isSelected()) {
                typeHouse = "TIPE 36";
            }else if (t45RadioButton.isSelected()){
                typeHouse = "TIPE 45";
            }else {
                typeHouse = "TIPE 54";
            }
            
            try{
                String sql = "INSERT INTO rumah (nama1, area2, tipe3, luas4, harga5, jumlah_cicilan6, cicilan_bulan7) VALUES ('"
                        + orderNameTxt.getText() + "''"
                        + areacb.getSelectedItem() + "''"
                        + typeHouse + ","
                        + largeLandTxt.getText()+"','"
                        + totalPriceTxt.getText() + "','"
                        + instalmentAmountTxt.getText() + "','"
                        + instalmentMonthTxt.getText() + "')'";
                Connection conn = (Connection)ConnectionDB.connectDatabase();
                PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                pst.setString(1,orderNameTxt.getText());
                pst.setString(2, (String) areacb.getSelectedItem());
                pst.setString(3,typeHouse());
                pst.setString(4, largeLandTxt.getText());
                pst.setString(5, totalPriceTxt.getText());
                pst.setString(6, instalmentAmountTxt.getText());
                pst.setString(7, instalmentMonthTxt.getText());
                pst.execute();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(PaymentForm.class.getName()).log(Level. SEVERE, null, ex);  
            }
            
            OptionMenu optionMenu = new OptionMenu();
            optionMenu.setVisible(true);
            this.getDesktopPane().add(optionMenu);
            this.dispose();
            
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include the debugging stacktrace and the sample input.

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Answer (score 1):

What you have there is a mashup of code that creates an SQL string by string-bashing (bad!) with code that uses a `PreparedStatement` to *avoid* string-bashing.  In effect, you have created your statement without any `?` placeholders, and then tried to supply parameter values for them.

I strongly recommend that you read [this Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) on using JDBC prepared statements.  It is important that you understand what you are doing when you use `PreparedStatement`, and *why you are doing it*.   If you don't *understand* what you are doing, you are liable to write **insecure** code.

---

The fix is to change the SQL to something like this:

```
    "INSERT INTO rumah (nama1, area2, tipe3, luas4, harga5, " +
    "jumlah_cicilan6, cicilan_bulan7) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
```

and then make sure that the correct value for each parameter is injected using the `setString` calls below.

And read the tutorial; see above.